# How can I make rendering animations more efficient?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I'm working on this blender project and I rendered a 30 second animation in cycles and it took 12 hours. This isn't much of a problem but when I woke up the next morning it only rendered a third of the clip. I assumed my computer went to sleep during the process so I tried again today and I was successfully able to render it. Although I had to convert the footage to be able to view it. Is there a way where I can prevent this from happening again? I'm fine with long renders, I'd like to render faster but I don't have time to upgrade my pc in the meantime; however, I just want to render overnight without risk of loosing footage.

Comment: Are you rendering with Eevee? Eevee is much faster than Cycles. And there are some ways to speed up your render with Cycles if you use it. Also, you can render a series of PNGs (or JPGs), instead of a movie, it allows you to stop and start again the rendering whenever your want.

Comment: As moonboots said, it's always good for animations to be rendered as image sequences and then put together as movie. If some short animation only takes 5 minutes you maybe won't mind to render it completely again if it fails rather then having to do a separate image to movie conversion. But especially longer renders are better done in image sequences. The important part is only to uncheck _Overwrite_ in the _Output Properties_ so that after rendering half a movie it doesn't start all over again and overwrite the already rendered images. Of course you could also manually set the render range.

Comment: PNG is the slowest image format to read and write with Blender, and JPEG while faster is really hurting the quality. I'd rather use TIFF, TGA Raw, or EXR with a lossless compression.

Comment: That being said, making your scene render faster really depends on your render engine and your scene content. So if you want advices more precise than lowering the samples and resolution, I highly advise you to pack, compress and share your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here, or at least add screenshots of your rendered scene, render settings and output settings. Also indicate your processor name, system RAM amount, graphics card name and memory.

Comment: @L0Lock I guess when rendering an animation of 30 seconds takes 12 hours then the speed difference of the file types is really negligible. And if the goal is to make a movie out of it afterwards, the image's reading speed is also completely irrelevant, the most time will be used by the video encoding process itself. For the movie file playback speed it's also irrelevant what kind of image file you chose before. But of course you're right about JPEG - that's not good for the quality. I prefer EXR with DWAA compression - no noticeable quality loss and a much smaller file than the PNG.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this. Writing speed is exponentially-ish relevant the more frames you have to render and the bigger the resolution is. I personally often encounter cases where a PNG can take 30 seconds to be written, vs up to 5s for other formats. For your example of 30s animation, at 24fps that's a difference of 6 h (21600s) for PNGs vs 1h (3600s). If rendering alone takes 12h, the whole thing is 18h or 13h total with file writing. That means leaving the overnight isn't enough in one case.

Comment: Reading speed, although less harmful than writing, can also matter when you need review that into your review tool, or send to edit. If you don't want to have your playback all the time pending for caching. A solution to that is to spend some time pre-caching everything once before working on things, but depending on the project or the hardware, you can't fit everything into your memory, or you are doing heavy edits that negates the interest of pre-caching. Hence my systematical flee off JPEGs and PNGs in favor of EXR and TGA Raw. They basically remove all these issues, like dark magic!

Comment: @L0Lock Hmmm... okay, I don't know about your computer, but I have never ever saved a PNG file that took so long. At least not up to an image size of 4k, and I guess the movies we are talking about in this question are no larger than that. The longest time after the initial render is usually taken by the compositing which isn't really fast in Blender. And anyway, about reading speed... you're talking about review tools or "send to edit". This might be relevant on some kind of production, I agree with you on that - but as beginner's tip regarding the fact he only got half a movie, not so much.